# main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'variable_name'

Tags: c

I am a complete newbie to C (started 6 hours ago) and I know there are a wealth of online references that I should (and will) look at in detail, but for now, I have an emergency and need help. I have a project folder containing the following files:

```
boundary_val.c
boundary_val.h
helper.c
helper.h
init.c
init.h
main.c
main.o
sor.c
sor.h
uvp.c
uvp.h
visual.c
visual.h
makefile
```

main.c should call these other functions found in the listed files.

the makefile reads as follows:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -Werror
.c.o:  ; $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

OBJ =   helper.o\
        init.o\
        boundary_val.o\
        uvp.o\
        main.o\
        sor.o\
        visual.o


all:  $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o sim $(OBJ)  -lm

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $*.o

clean:
    rm $(OBJ)

helper.o      : helper.h 
init.o        : helper.h init.h 
boundary_val.o: helper.h boundary_val.h 
uvp.o         : helper.h uvp.h
visual.o      : helper.h
sor.o         : sor.h

main.o        : helper.h init.h boundary_val.h uvp.h visual.h sor.h
```

when I run `make main` in the terminal i get the following error:

```
gcc   main.o   -o main
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'read_parameters'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'init_uvp'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'calculate_dt'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boundaryvalues'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'calculate_fg'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'calculate_rs'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'sor'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'calculate_uv'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'write_vtkFile'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'write_vtkFile'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'free_matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'free_matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'free_matrix'
main.o:main.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'free_matrix'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

these undefined references are functions that are defined in the other files and linked to the main.c file with the following:

```
#include "helper.h"
#include "visual.h"
#include "init.h"
#include "sor.h"
#include "boundary_val.h"
#include "uvp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

seems like `make` is reading main.o instead of main.c, could someone please tell me what is going on?

EDIT:

ran `make clean` and got this error:

```
rm helper.o init.o boundary_val.o uvp.o main.o sor.o visual.o
rm: cannot remove `helper.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `init.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `boundary_val.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `uvp.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `sor.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `visual.o': No such file or directory
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Comment: try running `make clean` and then `make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `make main`, you are actually calling `make` with the target `main`, which doesn't exist in your makefile. The target `all` is a special target that is built when no target is specified, in this case by using `make` alone. When you called `make main`, no targets named `main` were found, so `make` inferred that it should build that target using the already present `main.o` object file. You can see this from the line

```
gcc   main.o   -o main
```

Also, you should add the `-f` flag to the `rm` command in the `clean` target so that it ignores non-existent files (you only want to clear everything afterall).

```
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

TLDR; you should use `make` alone to build the `all` target.

See this makefile tutorial for more information on how to build a makefile : http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction

Comment: I dont quite get what you are saying, but can you please simply show what that code would look like

Comment: When building your project, you should be using `make` and not `make main`. That's all, also remember to change the clean target as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: alright, done - at least running make alone did not throw any errors. But how to actually run the main.c?

Comment: What do you mean by running the main.c ? When running `make` you compile the executable `sim` from the different source files. You can run the `sim` executable afterwards.

Comment: I mean that I have some code in main.c and I would like to run it. From what I have learned so far you would write "make main" to run the code in main.c. I know this is not the case, but its all i know atm

Comment: If your main.c file contains the `main` function, and your code is in that, then it will be executed when you launch the `sim` executable. You never actually "run" the main.c, but the executable that is the result of the compilation of the main.c.

Comment: Just type `make all` and then `./sim`.

Comment: @FreeSalad, thank you for effort and patience, I will accept your answer, but future readers of this question should know that Michael Walzs solution is the one I was looking for